# No response from server side (basic java client-server)

Tags: java, io, client, client-server

Hi I struggle with my client/server homeworks in java

I have to connect to a given server and do some "talking", but I have a problem where after I write to the server I get no response from it (timeout in tests before my "never reaches" comment in the code)

```
    public void run(PrintStream sysout, String host, int port, String myname) {
    OutputStream out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        try{
            this.connect(host,port); // same as clientSocket constructor 
            out = this.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out.write(myname.getBytes());
            out.flush();

            String income = in.readLine(); // never reaches !!!


            sysout.print(income);
            sysout.flush();
            out.close();

        }catch(IOException e){
            sysout.println(HelloServer.ERR_MESSAGE);
            sysout.flush();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the issue on your server or your client?  (If you're not sure, a network monitoring tool such as Wireshark can help you to find out.)

Comment: i did not code a server, i have attached tests i supose to pass, and it throw me timeout after 4 secs which means i dont get a response.

Comment: Are you sure the passed-in `host` and `port` are correct? If not, the timeout makes sense.